# Find if ancestor has a certain CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there is an easier way to check if an element has an ancestor with a particular class.

Consider the following HTML code:

```
<ul id="uniqueID" class="parentClass">
    <li class="subclassA">
        <div class="subclassB">
            <nobr>
                <a href="#" class="subclassC1" data="MyText"></a>
                <a href="index.php/things" class="subclassC2" style="">MyText</a>
            </nobr>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="subclassA"> ... </li>
    <li class="subclassA"> ... </li>
    <li class="subclassA"> ... </li>
</ul>
<div>other elements in this page which I want to select</div>
```

Right now, I can select the element `<a href="index.php/things" class="subclassC2" style="">MyText</a>` by using a jQuery selector checking the href for a particular format. What I can then do is do `.parent()` a known number of times (4) and then check the `class` attribute of that particular element that I've now moved to. While this is working just fine, I am curious if there is a better way to do it, perhaps one that lets me be a bit more dynamic?

PS. There are a lot of elements that I'm selecting that'll fit this `$('[href *= index.php]')` format, so I want to keep those but remove the ones that fall under the categorization where they are a descendant of a member of class `listclass`. Currently I'm just selecting all of the elements with the selector above, then using an `if` statement to check through and see if it fits this condition. Again, if there is a more efficient way to do this (perhaps select these certain elements in the first place?) I would love to hear about it.

Current code:

```
$('[href *= "index.php"]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('class') != 'parentClass'){
        //do things
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generalise you can use

> **.closest(".parentClass")**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `closest` and `is`:

```
$('[href*="index.php"]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).closest('ul').is('.parentClass')) {
        //do things''
    }
});
```

Comment: There's an actual method for it. `.hasClass('parentClass')` (note that you wouldn't need the period (.) using `hasClass`)

Comment: @ahren: I know, just prefer `.is`. There are many ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly assuming that the parent element is a `<ul>`, which is what I've observed so far. However, in the unlikely event that changes, is it possible to easily generalize this code to all elements?

Comment: You could use `.parents().eq(3)` to grab the fourth parent.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(this).parents("ul.parentClass").length == 0){
   //do something
}
```